# xquery newbie- how to display some text in nested if-else

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to run the following XQuery code-

```
declare variable $doc="E:\Arvind\Workspace\XML\test.xml"
let $page_title:= $doc//title[contains(.,'Error 404')]
let $assignee_block := $doc//div[@class="patent_bibdata" and contains(.,'Original        Assignee')]
for $assignee_link in $assignee_block/a 
for $assignee_link_url in $assignee_link/@href
where  contains($assignee_link_url,'inassignee') 
 return
if($page_title) then
     '404'
 else if ($assignee_block) then 
        return data($assignee_link)
  else return 'Missing'
```

However I am getting this error-

```
 XQuery syntax error in #...) else return 'Missing'#:
 Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I display the static text 'Missing' in the final else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

**Quite obvious**:

`$doc` is declared as the *string* =`"E:\Arvind\Workspace\XML\test.xml"`

**On the next line:**

```
let $page_title:= $doc//title[contains(.,'Error 404')]
```

The XPath pseudo-operator `//` cannot be appied on a string.

**To correct this issue, change**:

```
declare variable $doc="E:\Arvind\Workspace\XML\test.xml"
```

**to**:

```
declare variable $doc=doc("E:\Arvind\Workspace\XML\test.xml")
```

Also, because `doc()` accepts an *URI*, the filepath must be presented as such:

```
declare variable $doc=doc("file:///E:/Arvind/Workspace/XML/test.xml")
```

Comment: Except that the doc() function expects a URI, not a Windows filename, so it should be doc("file:///E:/Arvind/Workspace/XML/test.xml").

Comment: @MichaelKay, Yes, I noticed that, but thought that the particular XQuery implementation of the OP might accept filepaths. Modified the answer to now include your observation, too.

Answer (score 0):

Within an `if` expression, there is no need to specify the `return` keyword. Next, variable declarations require `:=` instead of `=`:

```
declare variable $doc := "E:\Arvind\Workspace\XML\test.xml";
let $page_title := $doc//title[contains(.,'Error 404')]
let $assignee_block := $doc//div[@class="patent_bibdata" and contains(.,'Original        Assignee')]
for $assignee_link in $assignee_block/a 
for $assignee_link_url in $assignee_link/@href
where contains($assignee_link_url,'inassignee') 
return
  if($page_title) then '404'
  else if ($assignee_block) then data($assignee_link)
  else 'Missing'
```

During development, it may help to use an editor, such as the BaseX GUI or oXygen, that directly gives you syntactical error feedback.